# Почему в функции-конструкторе допускается объявление ранее объявленных переменных?

Tags: java, ооп, переменные, инициализация

Уважаемые senior'ы и к ним стремящиеся, подскажите, пожалуйста, новичку почему компилятор в принципе допускает такой код?

```
public class Cat {
    String name;
    int age;

    public Cat(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

Ведь по сути, внутри функции-конструктора, на время работы этой самой функции, объявляются переменные-параметры, значения которых ниже присваиваются переменным this экземпляра класса. Конечно, это могут быть и:

```
public Cat(String s, int a) {
    this.name = s;
    this.age = a;
}
```

И это ОК. Но почему компилятор допускает повторную инициализацию переменных с теми же именами (name, age) в первом коде?

```
...
String name;
int age;
public Cat (String name, int age) {
    ...
}
...
```

Чего я не понимаю?

Comment: Прочитайте про области видимости переменных в Java. Там подробно объясняется почему так. Более того, можно не только в классе - конструкторе использовать одинаковые имена, но и , например, в двух разных методах одного класса могут быть одинаковые имена локальных переменных и они не перепутаются компилятором.

Comment: ссылка this (ссылка на текущий объект) по умолчанию присутствует в любом не статическом контексте, поэтому можно обращаться к любому полю просто по имени без указания this и точки. Имена переменных в параметрах метода могут совпадать с именами полей объекта для лучшей читаемости кода, но в этом случае, чтобы компилятор мог различать две разных переменных с одинаковыми именами в одной области видимости (блоке кода или теле метода), то есть различать, где переменная из параметров, а где поле объекта, используется this.имя_поля

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По сути переменная - это значение по какому-то адресу в памяти. Название для переменных - это, можно сказать, упрощение для человека, которое в рантайме ничего не значит.

Переменные в параметрах конструктора и переменные у объекта Cat, хоть и могут называться одинаково, но будут храниться в разных местах в памяти и для компьютера ничего общего не имеют, тк хранятся по разным адресам в памяти. Названия нужны лишь для того, чтобы программист понимал, что делает.

Почему это разрешает компилятор? Так решили разработчики Java, чтобы не нужно было мучаться с названиями и можно было использовать одинаковые в таких случаях. А для идентификации переменной, к которой обращается программист в таких случаях, добавили ключевое слово this, которое уже и поясняет компилятору, что мы стучимся в кучу к объекту, а не берем из стека в функции, например.

Comment: В то время как в обычном куске кода, если мы пишем дважды: int x, int x, то тут уже переменные теоретически должны были бы хранится в одном месте. Но это невозможно, и поэтому - ошибка. И проще говоря, описанная выше ситуация, это фишка функции-конструктора? Верно?

Comment: @work8play да, верно!)

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ! :)

Comment: @work8play и не только функции-конструкторе, в любом методе кроме static можно обратиться к this.variable.

Comment: Я дилетант. Можете, пожалуйста, кусок подобного кода, где та же фишка, что и в конструкторе работает написать?

Comment: @work8play https://pastebin.com/raw/mdFjLU92 вот)) добавил в Cat метод rename(String name) с похожим кейсом. Форматирование не очень там, но будет понятно. Писал без IDE сразу в pastebin.

Comment: Ага, спасибо. :)